# Image zoom on Meteor App (Cordova)

Tags: android, cordova, meteor, apk

I use Meteor for an Android app, so it use Cordova

i simply open a local image in the /public folder by a link on an html template:

```
<a href="/pippo/Foto.jpg">Foto</a>
```

If i build for a WebApp and use it on my PC the image normally cover the screen, If I reduce the size of the browser window, the image is responsive.

Instead if I build for Cordova app, on click the image is opened, but it is fixed to the real size and so it go outside of the screen size. 
I cannot reduce the size or zoom, i can only move the image to left-right / up-down

Comment: You have probably specified a fixed viewport in your index.html

Comment: @Mikkel I leave it like Meteor untouched settings, and if i check by inspect it is ok
`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, minimum-scale=0.1">`

Infact if i build for WebApp all work, is only on mobile app the problem